# How to format QueryPath Xpath Mappings in Feeds Module

Tags: 7, feeds

I have an XML document with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ooh>
    <occupation>
      <title type="text">Accountants and Auditors</title>
    </occupation>
    <occupation>
      <title type="text">Another Title</title>
    </occupation>
  </ooh>
```

What do I enter in the QueryPath XML Parser to set the context to be Occupation and add the title as a new source? I tried //ooh//occupation but I keep getting this error: `CSS selector is not well formed.`

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that error isn't _"XML is not well formed"_ ? Your XML is invalid at the moment is all. Your query is valid, but if you want to extract the title it'll be something more like `//ooh/occupation/title/text()`

Comment: I had simplified the XML a little for this post, but I tried an XML validator and didn't get any errors. I updated the XML above to better reflect the actual XML. And I agree that "XML is not well formed" would be a sensible error, but it is specifying 'CSS selector is not well formed.'

Answer (score 1):

The context should be the outer most wrapper of each item, so if your XML is

```
<ooh>
  <occupation>
   <title>Some Title</title
  </occupation>
</ooh>
<ooh>
  <occupation>
   <title>Another Title</title
  </occupation>
</ooh>
```

The context would be `//ooh` and the children of 'ooh' would be entered as `occupation` and `occupation/title`.

If occupation is the outermost wrapper of each item like:

```
<ooh>
  <occupation>
   <title>Some Title</title
  </occupation>
  <occupation>
   <title>Another Title</title
  </occupation>
</ooh>
```

The context would be `//occupation` and the title would be entered as `title`